# Associations made in Rails API not serializing compatibly with Ember app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, ember-cli

I created a Rails API (using the rails-api gem) to be consumed by my Ember  app (using ember-cli).

My problem is that the associations I have set in my API don't seem to yield exactly what my Ember app is looking for, and I don't have an idea about what needs to be changed or done differently.

Below, describes where I currently am and the steps I took to get here.

1. I generated two scaffolds:

   ```
   rails g scaffold movement name:string movement_type:string

   rails g scaffold record max_effort:integer max_type:string movement:references
   ```

   Which produced:

   Models

   ```
   class Movement < ActiveRecord::Base
   end

   class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :movement
   end
   ```

   Serializers

   ```
   class MovementSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
     attributes :id, :name, :movement_type
   end

   class RecordSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
     attributes :id, :max_effort, :max_type
     has_one :movement
   end
   ```

   Migrations

   ```
   class CreateMovements < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       create_table :movements do |t|
         t.string :name
         t.string :movement_type

         t.timestamps null: false
       end
     end
   end

   class CreateRecords < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       create_table :records do |t|
         t.integer :max_effort
         t.string :max_type
         t.references :movement, index: true, foreign_key: true

         t.timestamps null: false
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. I ran `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

   Which produced:

   Schema

   ```
   ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150514184239) do

     create_table "movements", force: :cascade do |t|
       t.string   "name"
       t.string   "movement_type"
       t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
       t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
     end

     create_table "records", force: :cascade do |t|
       t.integer  "max_effort"
       t.string   "max_type"
       t.integer  "movement_id"
       t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
       t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
     end

     add_index "records", ["movement_id"], name: "index_records_on_movement_id"

   end
   ```
3. I created seed data (using the faker gem) and run `bundle exec rake db:seed`

   Seeds (rails/app/db/seeds.rb)

   ```
   movements = Array.new

   10.times do |movement|
     movement = Movement.create(
       name: Faker::Lorem.word(),
       movement_type: ['pushing', 'pulling', 'squatting'].sample()
     )
     movements.push(movement)
   end

   30.times do
     Record.create(
       movement: movements.sample(),
       max_effort: Faker::Number.between(1, 100),
       max_type: ['rep', 'sec'].sample()
     )
   end
   ```

   When I run `rails s`, the respective URLs show:

   At http://localhost:3000/movements

   ```
   {
     movements: [
       {
         id: 1,
         name: "dolor",
         movement_type: "pushing"
       },
       {
         id: 2,
         name: "suscipit",
         movement_type: "squatting"
       }
       ...
     ]
   }
   ```

   At http://localhost:3000/records

   ```
   {
     records: [
     {
       id: 1,
       max_effort: 90,
       max_type: "rep",
       movement: {
         id: 7,
         name: "quia",
         movement_type: "pushing"
       }
     },
     {
       id: 2,
       max_effort: 26,
       max_type: "sec",
       movement: {
         id: 3,
         name: "non",
         movement_type: "pushing"
       }
     }
     ...
   }
   ```
4. I set up my Ember adapter, serializer, and router for AMS compatibility

   Adapter

   ```
   export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
   });
   ```

   Serializer

   ```
   export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
   });
   ```

   Router

   ```
   var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
     location: 'auto'
   });

   export default Router.map(function() {
     this.resource('movements', function() {
       this.resource('movement', {path: ':id'}, function() {
         this.route('records');
       });
     });
   });
   ```
5. I set the same associations as in Rails to my Ember models

   Movement

   ```
   export default DS.Model.extend({
     name:         DS.attr('string'),
     movementType: DS.attr('string'),
     records:      DS.hasMany('record')
   });
   ```

   Record

   ```
   export default DS.Model.extend({
     maxEffort: DS.attr('number'),
     maxType: DS.attr('string'),
     movement: DS.belongsTo('movement')
   });
   ```
6. I set up the respective Ember routes

   Movement (app/routes/movement.js)

   ```
   export default Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function(params) {
       return this.store.find('movement', params.id);
     }
   });
   ```

   Records (app/routes/movement/records.js)

   ```
   export default Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function() {
       return this.modelFor('movement').get('records');
     }
   });
   ```
7. I run `ember s --proxy http://localhost:3000`

   Results:

   All the movements are populated and behaving as expected in the app's UI. However, this is not the case for their associated records. Ember Inspector reveals no records have been loaded.

**Concluding thoughts:**

It seems to me that the movements JSON returned by rails should show some reference to records. I attempted this by adding the explicit association to both the movement model and serializer:

```
    class Movement < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :records  
    end

    class MovementSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id, :name, :movement_type
      has_many :records
    end
```

This only created an error when I tried to run the Rails server.

My other hunch is that my seeds.rb code is the problem. It is my first time using Faker, and I'm still no expert in Ruby.

I am stuck, and sure that it is do to my lack of experience with one of, or both, Ruby/Rails and Ember.
I hope with everything I have included here that it will be an easy mistake for someone more experienced to spot.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your records json, should look something like this, according to ember json convention
http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/

```
{
  records: [
  {
    id: 1,
    max_effort: 90,
    max_type: "rep",
    movement_id: 3
  }],
  movements: [
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "quia",
    movement_type: "pushing"
  }
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "quia",
    movement_type: "pushing"
   }
 ],
}
```

Deep nesting is kind of hard, if is absolutely necessary, as in using it all in the same template with their own outlets. If not make just a separate route.

Also if you are struggling with deep nesting you can create your own custom rest adapter pointing to an url.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late to answer to this question, but it might be helpful if you could add `embed :ids, embed_in_root: true` to `MovementSerializer` class in `Rails` side. I have had almost the same problem without adding that.